# How to add pre-hook in keystonejs?

Tags: keystonejs

I want to add multiple select options field. But the docs [state](https://keystonejs.netlify.com/api/field/select) that doesn't allow for multiple select. But recommends pre-hook for that case.

> Stores a String or Number in the model. Displayed as a select field in
>   the Admin UI. Does not allow for multiple items to be selected. If you
>   want to provide multiple values, you can use TextArray or NumberArray,
>   although neither will have the same constrained input. **You can limit
>   the options using a pre-save hook.**

I search for pre-hook but it seems came from mongoose. And in my case, I create the model using Keystone so that I can use it in admin page

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var MyModel = new keystone.List('MyModel');

MyModel.add({
    aField: { type: Types.TextArray, required: false, initial: true },
});
```

so how do I create the pre-hook? for example, I want to limit the TextArray to be set of ('a','b','c')?

Comment: A Keystone model *is* a Mongoose model. You would add the `pre` hook in exactly the same way you do in Mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

I have set up pre-save hooks like this (or something similar to this. Did not test this code).

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

/**
 * Musician Model
 * ==========
 */

var Musician = new keystone.List('Musician', {
    map: { name: 'title' },
    autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'title', unique: true },
});

Musician.add({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    published: { type: Types.Boolean, default: false },
    musicianId: { type: String, note: noteUpdateId },    
});

Musician.schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    console.log(this.title);
    console.log(this.isNew);
    if (this.isNew) {
        // generates a random ID when the item is created
        this.musicianId = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8);
    }
    next();
});

Musician.defaultColumns = 'title, published, musicianId';
Musician.register();
```